# Should lombok have a provided scope in spring-boot-dependencies?

Tags: spring-boot

Based on the Project Lombok documentation the lombok dependency should be a provided scope (https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven). Should that scope be defined within the `<dependencyManagement>` of the spring-boot-dependencies pom.xml?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The spring-boot-dependencies pom.xml is just a description of libraries versions that work well together. They are defined in dependencyManagement.

If you have a Spring Boot application and you want to use lombok, you have to explicitly say that in a 'dependency' section in your project pom, but you can exclude the version as this is already defined in spring-boot-dependencies. And you can also declare that the dependency is 'provided' or better yet 'optional'.

`<scope>provided</scope>` means that the library is needed for compilation and 
test classpath, however it is provided by some sort of container

`<optional>true</optional>` means that a library is needed for compilation, but it is not necessary at runtime

---

Edit: it seems that Spring Boot maven plugin always packages your dependencies, even if you declare them as optional or provided, at least when you package your app as a jar, I didn't test this with a war.

The reason is that a jar contains an embedded servlet container and Spring Boot packaging needs to provide this container with the provided libraries, makes sense! (thank you @Peter Wippermann).

I guess the conclusion is that it doesn't really matter if you provide a scope for lombok when packaging a jar with Spring Boot maven plugin, as the library will always get packaged, unless you want to use the scope for semantic reasons...

For lombok not be included in the package you just need to configure the Spring Boot maven plugin with the exclusion configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You may not omit the `provided` scope! Even if marked as optional, the lombok.jar would be included in your application deployment package otherwise. Other than your explanation, `optional` is used for dependencies that **might be used at runtime** (a very rare case). Lombok is definitely not needed at runtime so declaring it to be optional is not correct.

Comment: are you referring to how Spring Boot plugin (re)packages a jar?

Comment: so, I just experimented with a demo project from spring initializr (SB version 1.5.17) and whether I use `<scope>provided</scope>` or `<optional>true</optional>` the application packaged always contains lombok.jar in BOOT-INF/lib, to my surprise...

Comment: The Maven team tried to solve [a very special problem with the optional flag](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). On top of that, Spring Boot does it all different: When repacking the jar to include all runtime-dependencies it also includes `provided` dependencies since it also embeds Tomcat as runtime environment. Here you have to [exclude Lombok explicitly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html).

Comment: So, it doesn't matter which scope you set, doesn't matter even if you bother to set it, because Spring Boot plugin will always package the dependency for you, unless you exclude it explicitly in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Yes, this is the pragmatic approach. This is how it works with Spring Boot in practice. On the other hand there is the intended usage of scopes by Maven. And in addition, if you don't set the scopes right, other tools might break. So better adhere to the standard and define the scopes as it has been intended by Maven.